# Как запарсить сайт?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, error404

Код:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeatifulSoup


def get_html(url):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    return response.read()

def main():
    print(get_html('https://www.weblancer.net/'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Ошибка:

```
File "pars.py", line 2, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeatifulSoup
ImportError: cannot import name 'BeatifulSoup' from 'bs4' (C:\Users\Владимир\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py)
```

Comment: BeautifulSoup****

Comment: а где вы  bs4 используете?

Answer (score 0):

Вам же питон написал в чем ошибка. Ошибка в подключении бьютифулсоуп-а. Во первых, как написанно выше, где вы вообще его используете в вашем коде? Вы только реквест либу используете(в принципе, ее тоже может хватить, смотря какая у вас задача) Во вторых, у вас банально ошибка в написании названия компонента. Смотрите внимательно, как у вас написано слово BeautifulSoup, надо так. Если вы хотите написать что то типо бота-автопостера для этой биржи (что не совсем легально кстати), то это далеко не лучшее решение. Тут лучше подойдет Selenium(управление браузером в автоматическом режиме) При должных стараниях, можно создать систему, которая будет почти полностью имитировать человеческое поведение на бирже, что поможет избежать блокировок и минимизировать кол-во выскакиваемой каптчи:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

[Гайд по подключению библиотеки BeautifulSoup и парсингу с ее помощью](https://python-scripts.com/beautifulsoup-html-parsing)